# Program won't load to selected database, makes a copy in debug folder

Tags: c#, sqlite, csv

This program is supposed to take a csv file and load it to a sqlite database that the use specifies a path to. Rather than trying to load the values to the selected database it creates a copy of the database in the debug folder and then throws an error because the table doesn't exist in the new db. I can't find where it's deciding to make a new file rather than using the existing one.

```
using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" + db3FilePath + "; Synchronous=Off"))
{
    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, CSVRecord> kvp in csvDictionary.Skip(1))
        {
            //checks for duplicate records
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Accounts WHERE SDM_ACCT='" + kvp.Value.sdmacct + "'";
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count < 1)
            {
                WritetoDatabase.WritetoAccountsTable(kvp.Value.description, kvp.Value.priority, db3FilePath);
                WritetoDatabase.WritetoDirectoryTable(kvp.Value.number, kvp.Value.active, db3FilePath);

                recordCount++;
                //updates the progress bar and text field showing %
                int progress = y++ * 100 / (csvDictionary.Keys.Count -1);
                progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Value = progress));
                progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Update()));
                lblStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lblStatus.Text = "Writing records to database: " + progress.ToString() + "% Complete"));
                lblStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lblStatus.Update()));
            }
            else
            {
                WritetoDatabase.WritetoDirectoryTable(kvp.Value.number, kvp.Value.active, db3FilePath);
                y++;
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is a copy of the method that writes to the database.

```
public static int WritetoAccountsTable(string Comment, int PriorityInt, string filePath)
        {
            using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" + filePath + "; Synchronous=Off"))
            {
                using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Accounts(Description,Priority) 
                                                        values(@Comment,@PriorityInt)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", Comment);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriorityInt", PriorityInt);
                    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

I've changed everything I can think of trying to find what's causing the problem. Maybe you will see something I can't.

Comment: Do you have the database file included in your Visual Studio Solution?  What's the value of db3FilePath?

Comment: No. The idea was that the database is going to be out on a server and the program was going to be pointed at the location using an `OpenFileDialog()` that saves the selected path to db3FilePath

Comment: And what is the value of `db3FilePath`?

Comment: In this case "C:\Users\bminster\Downloads\Directory.db"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the all-time dumbest things I have seen break a program. The Connection String `using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" + filePath + "; Synchronous=Off"))` has "data source". If it is not capitalized, "Data Source", it doesn't recognize it and goes to a default setting.